# Avoid wrong variable on branch commit

Tags: javascript, rest, svn, branching

Our frontend web software contains, inside a file called *url.js* a variable used as URL root for REST webservices.

```
var url = "https://devappserver:8080";
```

During development on developer PC, for testing purpose, the variable is often changed to

```
var url = "https://localhost:8080";
```

The problem is that often developers commits the file with variable pointing to *localhost* on the development branch.

We use Subversion as VCS.

Which should be the best practice to avoid the error?

Is there a tecnical solution to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea [from an older Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009/how-do-you-deal-with-configuration-files-in-source-control). Let *url.js* be your default config file which is under source control. In the code which loads the variables from that file, test for the presense of another file *url_local.js*, which contains an override assignment like

```
  url = "https://localhost:8080";
```

Include this file if it is present using one of the mechanisms discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files).

Do not put that file under source control. Instead, write a comment in *url.js* like

```
 // do not change the following line directly, instead do this in url_local.js
 var url = "https://devappserver:8080"
```

If necessary, you can also provide a file *url_local_example.js* in source control which everybody can use as a template for his *url_local.js* file.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make use of environment variables? Something on your development machines with the value of `DEV`, and something on your servers with the value `QA` or `TST` or `PRD`.
Then, in your code, something along the lines of

```
const urls = {
  dev: "https://localhost:8080",
  prd: "https://devappserver:8080"
};

let url;
if(envVariable === 'DEV') url = urls.dev;
else url = urls.prd;
```

Alternatively, you can store these sort of things in a configuration file and load the correct config file conditionally based on the environment variable.

Comment: Not sure if environment variable can be evaluated with JavaScript from a web page...

Comment: True. I read this as JavaScript on the backend, not the frontend. If that's the case than my answer does not apply.